# "Company or organization" dropdown could do with some deduplication

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I just got an email about my developer story CV thing, and I just so happen to have an update. However, I'm kind of spoiled for choice.

[image]

The strange thing is that Booking.com [is a customer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/booking-com), and you do have an icon for it, but somehow that is not an option here. (At the same time, "Booking.com BV" is closer to the actual legal name of the company, so...)

Comment: Unrelated: when I went to search for the company I page, ["booking"](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?searchTerm=booking&location=&range=20&distanceUnits=Km) was insufficient as a search query: you needed an [exact match](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?searchTerm=booking.com&location=&range=20&distanceUnits=Km) to show the relevant result. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. There is a lot of duplication :/

We've removed companies that don't appear on any Developer Story(~3K), but there is still more work to do as it hasn't fixed the example you provided. We've rolled out fixes to prioritise exact matches and also not to recommend companies that don't have an image and don't appear on any other Developer Story.

We're working on other improvements and ways to merge companies, and will be able to fix the exact problem you're seeing soon.

Comment: Maybe also add possibility to link directly to the company page in the jobs section?

Comment: @vesse I'm not sure I follow. Where would you like to link to the company from?

Comment: I'd likethe company link in my developer story job history to point to the company page in http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/ instead of the page that shows just company name and a link to a web page

Comment: @kit I agree with Vesse here, I'd like to link to the company page on jobs rather than the auto-generated one too. i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/Mediaburst rather than http://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/194863/mediaburst?storyType=1