# Handling of companies in Developer Story is confusing and restrictive

Tags: support, developer-story

So I have been poking through Developer Story (updating from my existing Careers profile) and my experience with Experience (pardon the tautology) entries quickly went downhill.

Oh, there are new fields! I should add some logos!

**Attempt 1.** Did you mean [this existing company entry]? Oh, I guess I did! Has logo already, though page seems sort of useless...

**Attempt 2.** Ok, I have entry for being moderator on one of SE stacks, let's add link and logo... TADA! You have created a new organization page, which you cannot edit, with logo that looks like crap due to too much padding! Wait, what?

What I *wanted* was a link and a logo on the entry.

What I *got* is organization entry implicitly created, which I have no credibility to author (I don't *own* the SE stack) and ability to *edit* anymore. This effectively locked me out of my own Experience entry.

This workflow of cementing couple form fields into implicit creation of company entry feels **ugh** big time. I had never seen a form with such unexpected and permanent side effects. I got thrown out of editorial process for *my* content and prohibited to get back to it.

Comment: There is a gear in the top right of your items that if you hover provides "edit" and "delete" in order to make changes.

Comment: @TravisJ Once the company entry is implicitly created I am no longer allowed to change its name/URL/logo in edit form, that's the problem.

Comment: Oh! I see what you are saying. Yes, that is absolutely true and should probably be addressed.

Comment: I changed this to support, as there doesn't seem to be much discussion required.

Comment: You can edit the name/URL/image after you press the x button in the Company input box. I agree that this is unintuitive and is definitely something we will be work on improving.

Comment: @js12 and then it will just keep creating slightly different company entries I assume (which is probably reason for a zillion of duplicates already, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336075/886380 )

Comment: @js12 sorry, was wrong assumption, it does edit the existing entry! Thank you, could you please post that as an answer for now?

Answer (score 2):

For now, you can edit the Name/Url/Image of an existing job story item by pressing the x button in the company input box. We are working on fixes that will improve this workflow.