# Developer story company logos are getting reset periodically

Tags: bug, developer-story

I've uploaded company logos for my work experiences, but they got reset to having no logos periodically.

When I get back to edit the experiences, the upload widget is disabled. I [click the X button on the title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336163/65732) and I re-upload the logo. The company page gets updated accordingly. However, it's just a matter of time for them to reset.

Comment: This reads more like a bug than anything else.