# Same company is listed twice in Jobs, needs merging

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, companies-page

This company is listed twice as
https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/271515/teradata and
https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/368736/teradata

These two should be merged as they have different people listed under them

Comment: As far as I know there is not actually any merge utility for this yet, but [duplication is a known problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336075/company-or-organization-dropdown-could-do-with-some-deduplication). Someone likely created a new one to update the details, since we don't allow editing those lists yet either and the current workaround is to just delete it from your story and create a brand new one by entering all the details manually.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for the extremely late response. Unfortunately, we haven't had a team working on developer story for a while. Thanks for the report. Merged!